# How I am getting double internet speed? Just wondering

Tags: networking, isp, internet-speed, fiber

I was wondering, how it is possible that I am getting double speeds?

I am paying for 100mbps, but sometimes I am getting over 200mbps (pic below).

I have fiber cable run to my apartment, then fiber to digital converter, Mikrotik RB2011UiAS-2HnD-IN, Cat 5e cable to my pc.

This behaviour is observed while downloading torrents.

[image: Router OS screen]

Speedtest result

[image]

**EDIT:** 200mbps is DOWNLOAD speed, not total of both directions.

Comment: I don't use torrent very much, so I can't be sure, but I think it uses compression when streaming. This won't help with multi-media files, which are already compressed, but will give good improvements with text files, office documents, ISO images, etc.

Comment: You are only getting 100Mbps service, not 200Mbps... When you get internet the advertised rate is the download rate, not a combination of the upload and download rates. Is an Ethernet port called a 200M port? No, it is a 100M port, but it is 100M in each direction for a total of 200M, still it is called 100M Ethernet.

Comment: @acejavelin I think you are confusing something. Advertised ratio - 100mbps TOTAL in both directions. I am familiar with speedtest results. But my router shows that there is throughput of more than 200mbps. My ISP offers some other plans up to 600mbps, and fiber to data is 1gbps. Though speed is just software limitation in crossover point.

Comment: Are you downloading through a VPN?

Comment: @ŽygimantasMarkevičius Whatever... then just consider yourself lucky I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For home high-speed internet service, at least in the United States, if only one speed number is quoted, it's usually just the download speed, not the sum of both directions.

Service is often designed to be asymmetric, with upload speed often only a fraction (1/2 to 1/10th) of the download speed. However, it's not uncommon for fiber service to be symmetric.

So you've got symmetric 100mbps fiber internet service: 100 mbps down and 100mbps up, for a total of 200mbps of aggregate bandwidth.

Comment: One time I remember I was downloading at 23.5MB/s and uploading 10MB/s, Total of more than 300mbps. I am not new to internet stuff, but still wondering. Like, maybe there is some flaws in systems, or offpeak speed, or ISP local client P2P?

Comment: Nope, simply gigabit router.

Comment: There is no flaw.  You are downloading at the capacity your ISP has given you